# How do I get the response cookie after logging with the Requests library?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website to get the shipping information for my company. I am able to log in to the website using Python's request library. The issue I am facing is that after I log in and try to navigate to a different URL that has the information I need the cookies change and logs me out.

When I look at the network in the dev tools I see that the cookies that it changes to are the response cookies. When I use .cookies to see if it was getting picked up, it only shows the request cookies.

I tried setting up a persistent sessions but that did not help. I then tried saving the cookies and got nowhere with that. I am not sure what else to do.

```
url = 'http://website/login'
creds = {'_method':'****','username':'*****','password':'*****'}

response = requests.post(url,data=creds)
token = response.cookies
response = requests.get('http://webiste/reports/view/17',cookies=token)
```

Comment: Try using [requests.Session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can try token = response.headers['Set-Cookie'].